# Run IIS Application inside Website without web.config

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, web-config, authorization

I have an ASP.NET Website hosted in IIS. I created an application namely "Images" under the website which points to a shared network folder which every domain has access to it.

My aim is to access the images from SSRS ReportServer via URL i.e., http://URL/Images/Filename.jpg

Since it's a public folder I don't want to create web.config file inside it. 
Can I set Windows Authentication/Authorization via IIS Settings ?

Currently It is inheriting the web.config settings from its parent Website. I want to override it using IIS Settings for the Application.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186088/store-web-config-file-in-different-folder Related? You can simply use a location tag in `web.config` of the web site to control settings of the image folder.

Comment: Instead of creating a sub-application for images, you should try creating a `virtual directory` mapped to shared network location.