# Store web.config file in different folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a website application configured in IIS to access Images.

For security reasons, I cannot store web.config file there.

Is it possible to store web.config file in different folder other than the application folder?

Comment: For what kind of "security reasons"? Make that clear, or there can be no answer to that. Often you can store everything (using the appropriate location tags) in `applicationHost.config` if you really want to be "safe".

Comment: You'd better delete this one if your true question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185326/run-iis-application-inside-website-without-web-config.